# compile java class of protocol buffer has compile time error

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol buffer 2.6.1 with Java 1.7.0.71.

and compiled simple test protocol buffer file.

```
option java_package = "my.sample";
option java_outer_classname = "Sum";
option java_generic_services = true;
option java_generate_equals_and_hash = true;
option optimize_for = SPEED;
message SumRequest {
    required string family = 1;
    required string column = 2;
} 

message SumResponse {
   required int64 sum = 1 [default = 0];
}

service SumService {
  rpc getSum(SumRequest)
    returns (SumResponse);
}
```

But in code below, memoizedHashCode is declared nowhere, so it throws compile error.

```
@java.lang.Override
public int hashCode() {
  if (memoizedHashCode != 0) {
    return memoizedHashCode;
  }
  int hash = 41;
  hash = (19 * hash) + getDescriptorForType().hashCode();
  if (hasFamily()) {
    hash = (37 * hash) + FAMILY_FIELD_NUMBER;
    hash = (53 * hash) + getFamily().hashCode();
  }
  if (hasColumn()) {
    hash = (37 * hash) + COLUMN_FIELD_NUMBER;
    hash = (53 * hash) + getColumn().hashCode();
  }
  hash = (29 * hash) + getUnknownFields().hashCode();
  memoizedHashCode = hash;
  return hash;
}
```

I saw online that adding

```
private int memoizedHashCode = 0
```

solved the problem, but this is I think just workaround.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memoizedHashCode` is defined in the base class `AbstractMessageLite`, which is part of the protobuf library.

You need to make sure that the version of `protoc` that you are using to generate the code exactly matches the version of `libprotobuf.jar` that you are bringing into your program. If the versions do not match, you can see the error you describe, as well as other errors.